# Haskell - defining functions

Tags: haskell

I am new to programming and to Haskell. I'm having trouble understanding how to define a function. Let's say I want a function that will return element in position *a* of a list *[b]*. For a specific *a* and *[b]* I can do this in the interpreter:

```
Prelude> [2, 3, 5, 6] !! 1
Prelude> 3
```

But I run into trouble if I try to make a function, either in the interpreter or in a text editor that is then loaded:

```
Prelude> let getElement a [b] = [b] !! a 
Prelude> getElement 1 [2, 3, 5, 6]
***Exception: <interactive>:17:5-27: Non-exhaustive pattern in function getElement
```

Comment: I have no compiler at reach, but you also could do `a` calls of `head` on `[b]`. Then you would learn some recursion.

Comment: use `b` instead of `[b]`

Comment: You'll need `let getElement a b = b !! a`. By `[b]` you mean a list of one element which is `b`. Read a Haskell tutorial, it will help.

Comment: @mike, that's `tail` you need `a` applications of, not `head`.

Comment: if you use ghci, i'd recommend to the changes in your editor and save them in a .hs file which you the load using `:r <filename>.hs`; the error message you get some input combinations are not covers by the function definition you have provided

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> let getElement a [b] = [b] !! a

Your function takes one argument `a` of type `Int`, since `(!!)` second parameter is an Int, and `[b]` pattern matches on a list with one element.

It looks like you were trying to tell the complier that the second parameter should be a list.  To do this you normally use the type signature.

In a file:

```
getElement :: Int -> [b] -> b
getElement a bs = bs !! a
```

This type of function is considered partial since you can give it an integer that causes the function to fail and throw an exception, such as a negative number or trying to access an index larger then the list. [This chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html) in real world Haskell has some information on partial function. The Haskell wiki in on the programming guidelines page has [some advise too](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Programming_guidelines#Partial_functions).

You may want to look at the 
[safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) package and how they define [headMay](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/safe/latest/doc/html/Safe.html#v%3aheadMay) for a total, rather then partial, implementation.

Edit: `b` changed to `bs` as recommend by Rein Henrichs below, as he points out it does make it easier to read and is a rather common idiom.

Comment: Slightly less confusing to call it `getElement a bs = bs !! a`.